# CUDA invalid device symbol error

Tags: cuda, nvcc

the code below compiles just fine. But when i try to run it, i got

```
GPUassert: invalid device symbol file.cu 114
```

When i comment lines marked by (!!!) the error wont show up. My question is what is causing this error because it gives me no sense.

Compiling with nvcc file.cu -arch compute_11

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>

#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
#define THREADS 64
#define BLOCKS 256
#define _dif (((1ll<<32)-121)/(THREADS*BLOCKS)+1)

#define HASH_SIZE 1024
#define ROUNDS 16
#define HASH_ROW (HASH_SIZE/ROUNDS)+(HASH_SIZE%ROUNDS==0?0:1)
#define HASH_COL 1000000000/HASH_SIZE


typedef unsigned long long ull;

inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
  if (code != cudaSuccess) 
  {
  //fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
  printf("GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
  if (abort) exit(code);
  }
}

__device__ unsigned int primes[1024]; 
//__device__ unsigned char primes[(1<<28)+1];
__device__ long long n = 1ll<<32; 
__device__ ull dev_base;
__device__ unsigned int dev_hash; 
__device__ unsigned int dev_index; 

time_t curtime;

__device__ int hashh(long long x) {
  return (x>>1)%1024;
}
// compute (x^e)%n
__device__ ull mulmod(ull x,ull e,ull n) {
ull ans = 1;
while(e>0) {
    if(e&1) ans = (ans*x)%n;
    x = (x*x)%n;
    e>>=1;
}
return ans;
}

// determine whether n is strong probable prime base a or not.
// n is ODD
__device__ int is_SPRP(ull a,ull n) {
  int d=0;
  ull t = n-1;
  while(t%2==0) {
      ++d;
      t>>=1;
  }
  ull x = mulmod(a,t,n);
  if(x==1) return 1; 
  for(int i=0;i<d;++i) {
      if(x==n-1) return 1;
      x=(x*x)%n;
  }
  return 0;
}


__device__ int prime(long long x) {
//unsigned long long b = 2;
//return is_SPRP(b,(unsigned long long)x);
return is_SPRP((unsigned long long)primes[(((long long)0xAFF7B4*x)>>7)%1024],(unsigned long long)x);
}

__global__ void find(unsigned int *out,unsigned int *c) {

unsigned int buff[HASH_ROW][256];
int local_c[HASH_ROW];
for(int i=0;i<HASH_ROW;++i) local_c[i]=0;

long long b = 121+(threadIdx.x+blockIdx.x*blockDim.x)*_dif;
long long e = b+_dif;
if(b%2==0) ++b;
for(long long i=b;i<e && i<n;i+=2) {
    if(i%3==0 || i%5==0 || i%7==0) continue;
    int hash_num = hashh(i)-(dev_hash*(HASH_ROW));
    if(0<=hash_num && hash_num<HASH_ROW) {
    if(prime(i)) continue;
    buff[hash_num][local_c[hash_num]++]=(unsigned int)i;
    if(local_c[hash_num]==256) {
        int start = atomicAdd(c+hash_num,local_c[hash_num]);
        if(start+local_c[hash_num]>=HASH_COL) return;

        unsigned int *out_offset = out+hash_num*(HASH_COL)*4;
        for(int i=0;i<local_c[hash_num];++i) out_offset[i+start]=buff[hash_num][i]; //(!!!)
        local_c[hash_num]=0;
    }
    }
}
for(int i=0;i<HASH_ROW;++i) {
  int start = atomicAdd(c+i,local_c[i]);
  if(start+local_c[i]>=HASH_COL) return;
  unsigned int *out_offset = out+i*(HASH_COL)*4;
  for(int j=0;j<local_c[i];++j) out_offset[j+start]=buff[i][j]; //(!!!)
}

}

int main(void) {
printf("HASH_ROW: %d\nHASH_COL: %d\nPRODUCT: %d\n",(int)HASH_ROW,(int)HASH_COL,(int)(HASH_ROW)*(HASH_COL));

ull *base_adr;
gpuErrchk(cudaGetSymbolAddress((void**)&base_adr,dev_base));
gpuErrchk(cudaMemset(base_adr,0,7));
gpuErrchk(cudaMemset(base_adr,0x02,1));
}
```

Comment: It might be irrelevant to the error but what do you mean by this line : if(0<=hash_num<HASH_ROW) {

Comment: thanks for the comment, it was a mistake but it does not solve the problem

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the error.  It compiles and runs without error for me.  what CUDA version?  what OS? what GPU?

Comment: Device 0: "GeForce 9800 GT"
CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          5.5 / 5.5
Kubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A rather unusual error.

The failure is occurring because:

- By specifying a virtual architecture only (`-arch compute_11`) you defer the PTX compile step until runtime (i.e. you are forcing JIT-compile)
- The JIT-compile is failing (at runtime)
- The failure of the JIT-compile (and link) means device symbols cannot be properly established
- Due to the problem with device symbols, the operation `cudaGetSymbolAddress` on the device symbol `dev_base` fails, and throws an error.

Why is the JIT-compile failing?  You can find out yourself by triggering the machine code compile (which runs the `ptxas` assembler) by specifying `-arch=sm_11` instead of `-arch compute_11`.  If you do that, you'll get this result:

```
ptxas error   : Entry function '_Z4findPjS_' uses too much local data (0x10100 bytes, 0x4000 max)
```

So even though your code doesn't call the `find` kernel, it must compile successfully to have a sane device environment for symbols.

Why does this compile error occur?  Because you are requesting too much local memory per thread.  [cc 1.x devices are limited to 16KB local memory per thread](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#features-and-technical-specifications), and your `find` kernel is requesting quite a bit more than that (over 64KB).

When I initially tried it on my device, I was using a cc2.0 device which has a higher limit (512KB per thread) and so the JIT-compile step succeeded.

In general, I would recommend specifying both a virtual architecture and a machine architecture, and the shorthand way to do that is:

```
nvcc -arch=sm_11 ....
```

(for a cc1.1 device)

This [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22140178/cuda-why-does-compute-20-code-fail-on-compute-35-device) may also be of interest, and the [nvcc manual](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#virtual-architectures) has more details about virtual vs. machine architecture, and how to specify the compilation phases for each.

I believe the reason the error goes away when you comment out those particular lines in the kernel, is that with those commented out, the compiler is able to optimize-out the accesses to those local memory areas, and optimize-out the instantiation of the local memory.  This allows the JIT-compile step to complete successfully, and your code runs "without runtime error".

You can verify this by commenting those lines out and then specify a full compile (`nvcc -arch=sm_11 ...`), where `-arch` is short for `--gpu-architecture`.

Answer (score 2):

This error usually means the kernel has been compiled for the wrong architecture. You need to [find out what the compute capability of your GPU is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA#Supported_GPUs), and then compile it for that architecture. E.g. if your GPU has compute capability 1.1, compile it with -arch=sm_11. You can also build an executable for more than one architecture.